# Python code to create a table in SQL using values from multiple tables and a for a specific ID

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a database HMS in Mysql and it contain 5 tables

- c_details
- fashion
- gaming
- restaurant
- room_rent & total

I have the table total was created with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TOTAL(CID VARCHAR(20) primary key,ROOMRENT INT ,RESTAURANTBILL INT ,GAMINGBILL INT, FASHIONBILL INT)
```

It is in the python code only as you can see below now I want to insert bills from fashion, gaming, restaurant, room*rent and cid used from c*_details , Cid is present in all the tables which is customer id

```
def totalAmount():
    global cid
    customer=searchCustomer()
    myConnection=sqlcon.connect(host="localhost",user=userName,passwd=password ,database="HMS" , auth_plugin='mysql_native_password' )
    if customer:
        global grandTotal
        global roomrent
        global restaurantbill
        global fashionbill
        global gamingbill
    if myConnection:
        csr=myConnection.cursor()
        createTable ="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TOTAL(CID VARCHAR(20) primary key,ROOMRENT INT ,RESTAURANTBILL INT ,GAMINGBILL INT, FASHIONBILL INT)"""
        csr.execute(createTable)
        sql= "INSERT INTO TOTAL(CID, ROOMRENT, RESTAURANTBILL, GAMINGBILL, FASHIONBILL) SELECT c_details.cid, room_rent.ROOMRENT, restaurant.RESTAURANT_BILL, gaming.GAMING_BILL, fashion.FASHION_STORE_BILL FROM c_details, fashion, gaming, restaurant, room_rent WHERE c_details.cid=fashion.cid and fashion.cid=gaming.cid and gaming.cid=restaurant.cid and restaurant.cid=room_rent.cid and room_rent.cid=%s"
        name = input("Enter Customer Name : ")
        grandTotal=roomrent + restaurantbill + fashionbill + gamingbill
        values= (cid)
        csr.execute(sql,values)
        csr.execute("COMMIT")
        csr.close()
        print("---------------------------------------------------")
        print("**********CUSTOMER BILL ************************")
        print("********** HOTEL ************************")
        print("CUSTOMER NAME : " ,name)
        print("ROOM RENT : SAR ",roomrent)
        print("restaurant BILL : SAR ",restaurantbill)
        print("FASHION BILL : SAR ",fashionbill)
        print("GAMING BILL : SAR ",gamingbill)
        print("___________________________________________________")
        print("\nTOTAL AMOUNT : SAR ",grandTotal)
        print("WE ACCEPT CASH AND CREDIT/DEBIT CARDS (VISA & MASTERCARD")
        print("---------------------------------------------------")
        csr.close()
```

This is the code in python i am using i want the output to be as that when user inputs a cid the code will fetch all the bills for the cid and create a table which contains the cid and bills from the other table and  if it is possible I don't whether it is or not I want a column grandtotal also present in the table total which would add all the bills i could not find a way to do that

The searchcustomer() code is:

```
def searchCustomer():
    global cid
    myConnection=sqlcon.connect(host="localhost",user=userName,passwd=password ,database="HMS" , auth_plugin='mysql_native_password' )
    if myConnection:
        csr=myConnection.cursor()
        cid=str.upper(input("ENTER CUSTOMER ID : "))
        sql="SELECT * FROM C_DETAILS WHERE CID= %s"
        csr.execute(sql,(cid,))
        data=csr.fetchall()
    if data:
        print(data)
        return True
    else:
        print("Record Not Found Try Again !")
    csr.close()
```

So if some knows the proper code it would be big help for me all I want is the code to insert values for a specific Cid which the user inputs and fetch bills from other tables for that cid and insert it and also a column that would add all the bills and

I have tried multiple methods but I get errors and errors - this is the current error

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c101' in 'where clause'

I am unable to find a way to fix this please help I am doing Hotel Management system project and this issue has really annoyed me

Comment: Does your database have a column in the table named c101 ?  It says it doesn't, so why would it try to look for one with your code?

Comment: no i want it to fetch that c101 value from the cid column you know where cid=c101 i want that

Comment: where cid = 'c101' try that .. you need to wrap your search term in single quotes.  What data type is that column by the way?  Is it Integer or VarChar ?

Comment: Actually sounds like its VarChar cause it can't be Integer, so that is why your original search failed.  If you search for where cid = c101 .. well that only works with INTEGERS as they are the value they say they are, where as the word C101 is NOT an integer, and more of a string, so you NEED to use the single quotes around them like this:
CID = 'c101'

Comment: Let me know if that fixed it so i can submit and answer for this question so you can wrap it up, or if you still have other problems.  thanks.

Comment: Actually i found it the correct code was 
        sql= "INSERT INTO TOTAL(CID, ROOMRENT, RESTAURANTBILL, GAMINGBILL, FASHIONBILL) SELECT c_details.cid, room_rent.ROOMRENT, restaurant.RESTAURANT_BILL, gaming.GAMING_BILL, fashion.FASHION_STORE_BILL FROM c_details, fashion, gaming, restaurant, room_rent WHERE c_details.cid=%s and fashion.cid=%s and gaming.cid=%s and restaurant.cid=%s and room_rent.cid=%s"

Thank you your comment actually made me rethink and find this

Comment: Excellent, glad to be of some help.  I know I was stabbing in the dark, but seems to have done the trick.  Good job on fixing your code!

Answer (score 0):

Well for anyone wondering what the correct turned out to be thanks to @easleyfixed who somehow helped
the correct code is this:

```python
def totalAmount():
    global cid
    customer=searchCustomer()
    myConnection=sqlcon.connect(host="localhost",user=userName,passwd=password ,database="HMS" , auth_plugin='mysql_native_password' )
    if customer:
        global grandTotal
        global roomrent
        global restaurantbill
        global fashionbill
        global gamingbill
    if myConnection:
        csr=myConnection.cursor()
        createTable ="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TOTAL(CID VARCHAR(20) primary key,ROOMRENT INT ,RESTAURANTBILL INT ,GAMINGBILL INT, FASHIONBILL INT)"""
        csr.execute(createTable)
        sql= "INSERT INTO TOTAL(CID, ROOMRENT, RESTAURANTBILL, GAMINGBILL, FASHIONBILL) SELECT c_details.cid, room_rent.ROOMRENT, restaurant.RESTAURANT_BILL, gaming.GAMING_BILL, fashion.FASHION_STORE_BILL FROM c_details, fashion, gaming, restaurant, room_rent WHERE c_details.cid=%s and fashion.cid=%s and gaming.cid=%s and restaurant.cid=%s and room_rent.cid=%s"
        values= (cid,cid,cid,cid,cid,)
        csr.execute(sql,values)
        fet= "select * from total"
        csr.execute(fet)
        data=csr.fetchall()
    if data:
        for i in data:
            name = input("Enter Customer Name : ")
            grandTotal=i[1] + i[2] + i[3] + i[4]
            print("")
            print("---------------------------------------------------")
            print("**********CUSTOMER BILL ************************")
            print("**********HOTEL ************************")
            print("CUSTOMER NAME : " ,name)
            print("ROOM RENT : SAR ",i[1])
            print("restaurant BILL : SAR ",i[2])
            print("FASHION BILL : SAR ",i[3])
            print("GAMING BILL : SAR ",i[4])
            print("___________________________________________________")
            print("\nTOTAL AMOUNT : SAR ",grandTotal)
            print("WE ACCEPT CASH AND CREDIT/DEBIT CARDS (VISA & MASTERCARD")
            print("---------------------------------------------------")
            drp="Drop table total"
            csr.execute(drp)
            csr.close()
            main() 
    else:
        print("ERROR GENERATING BILL TRY AGAIN")
    csr.close()
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Great that you found out the answer, and that you're posting it on here for everyone :) Two little points: instead of pasting the whole code block, it is more useful to discuss which exact code fixed your problem (maybe they are only 2-3 lines). That way your answer is much more readable! Also, don't forget to mark your answer as accepted: that helps in keeping Stackoverflow of high quality!